# Redirect all domains requests to 1 domain without `www.` on Divshot

Tags: javascript, redirect, url-rewriting, divshot

Kicking the tires on divshot.com with my middleman blog. I moved it over from Heroku, which uses rack to handle URL redirects/rewriting. I'm trying to duplicate some of that behavior on divshot, which uses HTML5 pushState ([superstatic](https://github.com/divshot/superstatic)) instead.

I have multiple domains that I want to redirect to 1 domain, and I want to redirect all `www.` requests directly to http://example.com (rather than http://www.example.com).

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few ways to tackle this:

1. Your DNS provider may offer the ability to make these kinds of redirects without having to use Divshot to do it.
2. If you have a high-performance app (i.e. a paid plan) we can manually configure our CDN to do those redirects for you.
3. You can detect host in JS and redirect that way (less ideal, I'd go with 1 or w).

Comment: I use DNSimple as my provider. The DNSimple template for Divshot had a CNAME `www.` record, which I removed, and then I added a URL record to redirect all subdomains to http://example.com (`*.example.com -> http://example.com). Should do exactly what I want, but It seems to be working for all subdomains except www.

Comment: Cancel that, the changes I made to my DNS in DNSimple seemed to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect a user to another page, you can use:

```
if(window.location.host === 'www.example.com') {
    window.location = "http://example.com";
}
```

or for IE only:

```
window.navigate("http://www.example.com");
```